# Enabling socks proxy in my browser is freezing my putty terminal

Tags: freeze, putty, ssh-tunnel, socks-proxy

Local system - Windows 8.1, Putty, Firefox with FoxyProxy addon (Socks5)

Remote server - Ubuntu 14.04 (headless)

When i enable FoxyProxy and use SSH tunneling, the putty session freezes and the webpages stop loading. This doesn't happen immediately though. The session works fine for 5 minutes and then everything freezes. I can create a new session but, the old session remains frozen and proxy fails.

Is there a way to find out what is causing the hiccup? Can wireshark help solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Changing MTU settings seems to have solved the problem. My home connection uses PPPoE with MTU set to 1460. I reduced my server MTU settings to 1460 and things improved. Still there was a noticeable lag, lowered MTU further down to 1432 and voila!